# Add and Remove Views in Android Dynamically in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I modified my code by referring to the "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically-in-kotlin". There was no error in my code, but the view added when running in the app was not visible. I have no idea what the problem is. Please help me!!

Activity to which the view is added

```
package com.akj.callback

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import com.akj.callback.databinding.ActivitySearchSubject2Binding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_search_subject_2.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_search_subject_2.to_go_check
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.choiced_subject_list.*
import java.util.*

class search_subject_2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding3:ActivitySearchSubject2Binding

    private var parentLinearLayout: LinearLayout? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_subject_2)

        parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout)

        binding3= ActivitySearchSubject2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding3.root)
        userList3.onItemClickListener= AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
                parent, view, position, id ->
            //parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            onAddField()

        }

        val user = arrayOf("abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg")
        val userAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,user)

        to_go_check.setOnClickListener {
            val intent6=Intent(this@search_subject_2,checkthesetting::class.java)
            startActivity(intent6)
        }

        binding3.searchView3.setOnQueryTextListener(object :androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                binding3.searchView3.clearFocus()
                if(user.contains(query)){
                    userAdapter.filter.filter(query)
                }
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                if(newText==""){
                }
                else{
                    binding3.userList3.adapter=userAdapter
                    userAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                }
                return false
            }
        })

    }
    fun onDelete(view: View) {
        parentLinearLayout!!.removeView(view.parent as View)
    }
    fun onAddField() {
        val inflater =
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val rowView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choiced_subject_list, null)
        parentLinearLayout!!.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout!!.childCount - 1)
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fdsvkgjh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

choiced_subject_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
            android:text="title_fdskhdsffsd"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="phone"
    
            />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:onClick="onDelete" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

activity_search_subject_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".search_subject_2">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.94" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.03" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.87" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/coner_search_bar"
        android:theme="@style/AppSearchView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline5"
        app:queryHint="강좌 검색"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        />




    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/to_go_check"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98"
        android:text="확인"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/coner_search_bar"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/to_go_check"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/njklsfd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="전공검색" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="교양검색" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="교수검색" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="정렬" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="학점:3" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="학점:2" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_subject_bar"
                android:text="학점:1"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userList3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
      
val rowView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_child_view, null, false)
   

Mainview.removeView(rowView)
```

Comment: what is Mainview?

Comment: Mainview is Viewgroup Where you have the add view